# Select data from multiple unrelated tables with LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Let's say I know ahead of time that the request I'm processing will require me to pull data from 5 different tables **that are not related** to populate different sections of a page.

Is there a way, and would it be more efficient, to combine these into a single database call that returns 5 different data sets?

Something like:

```
var all_data = context.Select(a => new {
     dataset1 = context.Table1.Where(b => b.XXX == XXX),
     dataset2 = context.Table2.Where(b => b.XXX == XXX),
     dataset3 = context.Table3.Where(b => b.XXX == XXX),
     dataset4 = context.Table4.Where(b => b.XXX == XXX),
     dataset5 = context.Table5.Where(b => b.XXX == XXX),
});
```

(obviously the above doesn't work) Then I can do whatever I need with each, for example:

```
GridView1.DataSource = all_data.dataset1;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView2.DataSource = all_data.dataset2;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

I feel this would be more efficient than sending 5 separate calls to the database but can't figure out how to do it. Thoughts welcome.

Comment: Future queries is what would work here. [There is a library in the wild](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) that enables that, it seems it should be up to date, but I haven't used it personally. I wish it was included in the framework though, similar to NHibernate's `Future`.

Comment: I'll check it out...was hoping for a solution that didnt require another library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be so quick to say "Obviously this doesn't work" . I think it does work. It should do what you want in a single query. 
I get why you would assume that it doesnt work though. It does look like separate queries and therefore separate round trips. But other examples I am reading (and my own experience ) seems to indicate it knows how to combine this into a single query.

See:
[Subquery with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685375/subquery-with-entity-framework)

Also:
Try putting a breakpoint in your code and use the debugger to inspect the IQueryable generated (all_data). It should have Sql that combines into a single query.

If I'm wrong here I'd certainly like to know more myself. If this doesnt work, a Union() certainly would work . Though it would be a bit ugly.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. `context.Select` doesn't even compile.