# Subquery with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, nhibernate

I'm porting a subsystem from *NHibernate* to *Entity Framework* and want to see the best way to port the following query to *EF*.

```
var date = DateTime.Now; // It can be any day
AccountBalanceByDate abbd = null;
var lastBalanceDateByAccountQuery = QueryOver.Of<AccountBalanceByDate>()
    .Where(x => x.AccountId == abbd.AccountId && x.Date < date)
    .Select(Projections.Max<AccountBalanceByDate>(x => x.Date));

var lastBalances = session.QueryOver<AccountBalanceByDate>(() => abbd)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Date).Eq(lastBalanceDateByAccountQuery)
    .List();
```

The account balance class is:

```
public class AccountBalanceByDate
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountBalanceByDate]
(
    [Id]        int NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] int NOT NULL,
    [Date]      [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Balance]   [decimal](19, 5) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

A sample data is (using numeric ids for better understanding):

```
Id | Date        | Account | Balance
------------------------------------
 1 | 2014-02-01  | 101     | 1390.00000
 2 | 2014-02-01  | 102     | 1360.00000
 3 | 2014-02-01  | 103     | 1630.00000
 4 | 2014-02-02  | 102     | 1370.00000
 5 | 2014-02-02  | 103     | 1700.00000
 6 | 2014-02-03  | 101     | 1490.00000
 7 | 2014-02-03  | 103     | 1760.00000
 8 | 2014-02-04  | 101     | 1530.00000
 9 | 2014-02-04  | 102     | 1540.00000
```

The *AccountBalanceByDate* entity hold the account balance in a specific day. If a day doesn't have a transaction, that day will not have an *AccountBalanceByDate* and we should look for the previous days to see the balance for that account.

If I query with the date *2014-02-01* I should get:

```
 No results
```

If I query with the date *2014-02-02* I should get:

```
 1 | 2014-02-01  | 101     | 1390.00000
 2 | 2014-02-01  | 102     | 1360.00000
 3 | 2014-02-01  | 103     | 1630.00000
```

If I query with the date *2014-02-03* I should get:

```
 1 | 2014-02-01  | 101     | 1390.00000
 4 | 2014-02-02  | 102     | 1370.00000
 5 | 2014-02-02  | 103     | 1700.00000
```

If I query with the date *2014-02-04* I should get:

```
 4 | 2014-02-02  | 102     | 1370.00000
 6 | 2014-02-03  | 101     | 1490.00000
 7 | 2014-02-03  | 103     | 1760.00000
```

If I query with the date *2014-02-05* I should get:

```
 7 | 2014-02-03  | 103     | 1760.00000
 8 | 2014-02-04  | 101     | 1530.00000
 9 | 2014-02-04  | 102     | 1540.00000
```

I can do this in Entity Framework using raw SQL, but it is not the ideal.

```
using (var context = new DbContext()) 
{ 
    var lastBalances = context.AccountBalanceByDate.SqlQuery(
        @"SELECT
            *
        FROM 
            [AccountBalanceByDate] AB
        WHERE
            DATE = (
                SELECT
                    MAX(Date) 
                FROM 
                    [AccountBalanceByDate]
                WHERE
                    AccountId = AB.AccountId AND DATE < @p0
            )", date).ToList(); 
}
```

It is preferred to go to database just one time, like in *NHibernate* and raw SQL, but using just *linq*, is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

Fixed results in the question.

SQL showing the sample query on GIST: https://gist.github.com/sergiogarciadev/275ec363070f2513b887

Entity Framework sample on GIST: https://gist.github.com/sergiogarciadev/9f7bd31a21363ee0b646

Comment: Your own SQL query DOES NOT produce the results you gave in your question! Querying for 2014-02-01 returns nothing! FIX your query first.

Comment: @AgentShark, please note that I have a subquery that reference the top table and it do that for each row. Then, for each row it gets its account id and get the max date. It returns me all the results in the max date of each account, the max date can be different for each account. It is the catch, my sample is correct, I double checked it again when you pointed it was incorrect.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, but I entered your exact data in SQL Server 2008 and ran your query. '2014-02-01' returns nothing. '2014-02-02' returns Ids 3,2,1. '2014-02-03' return Ids 5,4,1. '2014-02-04' returns Ids 7,4,6.

Comment: The SQL Sample is on GIST, the EF sample is on the way. And I was showing the wrong results (typing error), they are for the next day. For day '2014-02-01' are no results.

Comment: The EF Sample is on GIST, it results exactly the results in this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following query do exactly what I need with just one query to the database:

```
var accountBalance = context
    .AccountBalanceByDate
    .Where(a => 
        a.Date == context.AccountBalanceByDate
             .Where(b => b.AccountId == a.AccountId && b.Date < date).Max(b => b.Date));
```

Thanks @AgentShark for the help.

The code is on GIST: https://gist.github.com/sergiogarciadev/9f7bd31a21363ee0b646

Comment: During your testing, this didn't require multiple round trips?

Comment: No, you can inspect the generated SQL and it is just one SQL query.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, a solution. :)

```
var date = DateTime.Now; // It can be any day
var lastBalances = (from a in context.AccountBalanceByDate
        where a.Date < date
        group a by new {a.AccountId} into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault() into r
        select new
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            AccountId = r.AccountId,
            Date = r.Date,
            Balance = r.Balance
        }).ToList();
```

You wanted it in LINQ, but personally, I might of kept the SQL for maintainability.

Comment: I update the gist sample with your solution, please note that it stills incorrect. Indeed, I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: @SergioGarcia I have to disagree with you sir, Ids returned from this LINQ match Ids from the SQL. I just hard coded the date. I tested this in VS2013 against your test data.

Comment: Please check the gist. But I found a solution.

Comment: The **only** difference is that mine is ordered by AccountId.